# Creating a histogram from a TTree

Tags: tree, histogram, root-framework

I'm trying to create a 1D histogram from a TTree that contains only one variable.

```
TTree *tree = new TTree("tree", "");
tree->ReadFile("occupancyPerDataset.txt", "size");

TH1F *occupancy = new TH1F("occupancy", "Occupancy per Dataset", 100, 0,      0.063)
```

Above you can see I created the tree and filled it with the data from a `.txt` file. I then created the histogram with the number of bins, `x_low`, and `x_high` that I need. When I try to do

```
occupancy->Fill(tree);
```

or

```
occupancy->Fill(size);
```

I get an error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The the `Fill` method of TH1 (TH1F is daughter class) doesn't take the tree as parameter.

You have two options:

1. loop over the tree entries and fill them in the histogram one by one.

   e.g. by calling `tree->MakeClass("MYTREE")` and then manipulating the `Loop()` function in `MYTREE.C` by adding

   ```
   occupancy->Fill(VARIABLENAME);
   ```

   into the loop and execute the resulting code.
2. use the [Draw method of TTree](https://root.cern.ch/root/html534/TTree.html#TTree:Draw@2):

   ```
   tree->Draw("VARIABLENAME>>HISTOGRAMNAME");
   ```

Comment: Also `Project` method in `TTree` class.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for drawing and extracting a histogram from a TTree object, several of them are available in the ROOT tutorials which can be found online [here](https://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/tutorials/tree/index.html) or locally(if tutorials have been installed) under $ROOTSYS/tutorials/tree/.  The basic2 example may be helpful for what you are attempting to do.